# How is precedence of binary messages implemented in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: pharo

I was looking at the syntax of Pharo Smalltalk, and was wondering how is precedence of binary messages implemented.

How does one go about declaring such a binary message?

How does the system figure out the precedence over unary messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For implementing binary messages:

Yes, you can look at the number class for example. It has a lot of binary messages there. Or consider this method of `Object`:

```
-> anObject
    ^ Association basicNew key: self value: anObject
```

This allows you to evaluate `'five' -> 5` and get an association.

### For precedence:

This is done by a parser. So first of all it looks for keyword messages, then binary, then unary, then parents.

So if you have

```
collection add: 'five' -> 5
```

The parser will first of all parse `add:` with receiver `collection` then it parses `'five' -> 5` and puts it a a parameter of `add:`. This way the AST is composed in the way that keyword messages are more general and will be executed after their attributes are computed

### Where to find

In the latest versions of Pharo the parsing is done with `RBParser` (same parser used previously for refactoring). Keyword messages are parsed with `parseKeywordMessage` and binary with  `parseBinaryMessage`. The easies way to explore would be to put a one time breakpoint on `parseBinaryMessage` and execute something like

```
RBParser parseExpression: 'coll add: #five -> 5'
```

The debugger will stop on `parseBinaryMessage` so you can look at the stack and see how it is working. Pay attention, breaking once is important, otherwise you will get a debugger every time you compile a method or so on.

Comment: I see, so a binary message don't  differ from a keyword message in implementation, it just returns a specific class object with self and the other operator as arguments. I modified the question a bit to focus on precedence rules, that's what I was interested in specifically. Please read the question again. How does the system figure out the precedence over unary messages?

Comment: @unmircea updated. Essentially it's all about parser that knows precedence and creates correct ASTs

Answer (score 2):

In Smalltalk, all binary messages have the same precedence and are strictly evaluated from left to right. That is why

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

evaluates to `9` and not `7`, being evaluated as

```
(1 + 2) * 3
```

All unary messages have the same precedence and are evaluated from left to right. Their precedence is higher than the binary messages:

```
1 sin sqrt + 1 cos sqrt
```

is equivalent to

```
((1 sin) sqrt) + ((1 cos) sqrt)
```